# svelte and sveltestrap - issue with select inputs

Tags: bootstrap-4, svelte

I'm building an app with Svelte - fantastic!

I'm trying to use bootstrap 4 for the css, so I've added sveltestrap with `npm install` and included the bootstrap css globally as per instructions on sveltestrap's npm page.

I have an issue with select inputs. For some reason, just below the label, a standard text input appears with ul-type list of the options. Below this I get the select control I want - see attached screenshot [image: screenshot of problem].

Mystifyingly, the html is fine & correct, so I'm really puzzled as to what is going one here.

Here is the relevant .svelte:

```
<Form>
  <FormGroup>
    <Label for="verksamhetstyp">Verksamhetstyp</Label>
    <Input type="select" required name="verksamhetstyp" id="verksamhetstyp" bind:value={fastighet.verksamhetstyp}>
    <!--<option value=null></option>-->
    {#each verksamhetstyp as vtyp}
      <option value={vtyp._id}>{ vtyp._id }</option>
    {/each}
    </Input>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Here is the html generated by svelte:

```
<form class="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="" for="verksamhetstyp">Verksamhetstyp</label>
    <select required id="verksamhetstyp" class="form-control" name="verksamhetstyp" value="Skola">
      <option value="BMSS">BMSS</option>
      <option value="Daglig verksamhet">Daglig verksamhet</option>
      <option value="Förskola">Förskola</option>
      <option value="Lägenheter">Lägenheter</option>
      <option value="Skola">Skola</option>
      <option value="Äldreboende">Äldreboende</option>
      <option value="Övriga">Övriga</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

I get the same problem if I use "pure" html instead of sveltestrap's components.

Comment: Have you correctly add the css using `svelte:head`? Because as you can see in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-butterfly-0u674?file=/App.svelte:190-201) there is no styling issues.

Comment: I see. I had added the css in template.html, but the result is the same wherever I add the css. I'm using sapper & SSR, so am doing e.g. `import Form from 'sveltestrap/src/Form.svelte';` instead of `import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from "sveltestrap"` Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: Yeah probably you just need to import the components from the entry point (and not the component file directly). Should I wrote this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, problem was caused by a rogue hangover include of `materializecss.min.js` in `template.html`. This was from an earlier attempt of same app using materializecss instead of sveltestrap. Sorry!